# Do tomatoes or tomato pastes damage stainless steel cookware?

Tags: tomatoes, cookware, storage, stainless-steel

I enjoy making a good ragu, and I often want to let it sit in the stainless steel cookware so I can have leftovers the next day (not a commercial setting).  But I'm concerned about the acid from the tomatoes eating into the pot or pan.

Do tomatoes or tomato pastes harm the finish on stainless steel cookware if it sits overnight?

Answer (score 2):

I have stainless steal pots and pans and I have never had an issue storing food in them in the refrigerator. I make all kinds of stocks for soup and often store the stock in the pot overnight in the refrigerator to remove the fat layer the next day.

Comment: That's great to hear.  Do you make stocks with tomatoes or tomato paste?

Answer (score 1):

Stainless steel is nonreactive.  You should only have this issue with regular (non-stainless) steel.